# Jasper report deploying a report tor server-web client

Tags: jasper-reports, webclient, ireport, jasperserver

I want to deploy a report to jasper reports server-web client. In this context I'm following this:

> login screen > Reports > add resources  jasper reports > I setup my report  > I configure my data source  >  **select the data source from the repository**

when I would like to find my data source I can't see my data source among data sources even if I already create connection wıth database and generate my report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sollution of this problem is reinstalling jasper server 5.5.0 after that you should add data source  moreover jasper repots server is not so compatible wıth microsoft server 2008 therefore lınux server advised to use